# How to build a WebBrowser for android auto

Tags: android-auto

I've been trying to build my web browser for android auto with android studio for a few days.  But I can't see the webview widget inside a service.  I've searched the net but can't find much.  Some advice?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Android Auto is limited to Google Templates. You need to use latest car library.
Basically to do anything for Android Auto today - you need to match these guidelines: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/Android%20for%20Cars%20App%20Library%20design%20guidelines.pdf

This is official doc (there's list of available templates). There's no category you could even put your app there (even as a hack).

Comment: also there's no webview for android auto I guess ?

Comment: @ruben There isn't. Android Auto got only selected templates. For Android Automotive - you can use more freely APIs from Android (but here everythings depends - most automotive companies are going without GAS - which means you can't use any Google Services). But for Android Auto - only stuff showed in this PDF.